# Duplicate Loader's content multiple times via addChild()?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have small problem. I'm dynamically loading JPG file using Loader class. Everything works except if I want to tile the image few more times using addChild(loader.content) it just doesn't work. It always removes previous instance and leaves only the last one. I've tried everything but with no luck. Here's my code:

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true);
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaderDone);
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://127.0.0.1/blah/blah.jpg');
imageLoader.load(fileRequest, loaderContext);

var imageLoaderDone:Function = function(e){
    var k:int = landHolder.numChildren;
    while(k--) {
        landHolder.removeChildAt(k);
    }
    var howManyTimes:int = Math.ceil(1000 / e.content.width);

    var i:int = 0;
    while(i < howManyTimes) {
        var zombie:Sprite = new Sprite();
        zombie.addChild(e.content);
        zombie.x = i*zombie.width;
        landHolder.addChild(zombie); //here's the problem, it does not duplicate
        //landHolder is empty MovieClip placed on the stage
        i++;
    }

    landHolder.alpha = 1

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of a loaded image, you could simply clone its bitmap data.

```
var loadedBitmap : Bitmap = e.content as Bitmap;
var clonedBitmap : Bitmap;
for(var i:Number = 0; i<100; i++) {
    clonedBitmap = new Bitmap(loadedBitmap.bitmapData.clone());
    clonedBitmap.x = i*clonedBitmap.width;
    landHolder.addChild(clonedBitmap);
}
```

The other suggested solutions are good alternatives when you need to clone more than a simple image.

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution which I forgot to test. ;) It's working!

Answer (score 1):

The loaded content is a single instance of DisplayObject. What you are doing is to move this instance around the several sprites you create within your loop. Finally, your instance is added to the last sprite, and all the others are empty.

Diffent possibilities:

1. Try to set up a distinct loader for each sprite container - loading the same resource. The browser will cache the image, so it won't load it multiple times from the server.
2. Embed your image and create multiple instances of it.
3. Search for an algorithm to duplicate display objects using AS3.

   Found this: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?223798-ActionScript-3-Tip-of-the-Day&p=1939827#post1939827 but did not verify. I am sure there are solutions posted here already.

   Read also this answer: [AS3: Copying a Loader from one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293150/as3-copying-a-loader-from-one-object-to-another/3293397#3293397)

   Or this: http://blog.andredickson.net/?p=56

   Or this: [Duplicate image with Haxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501113/duplicate-image-with-haxe)